# In Google BigQuery, how to get storage size of a partition in time-partitioned table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I can query for storage size of a table in BigQuery using `SELECT size_bytes FROM dataset.__TABLES__ WHERE table_id='mytable'`, but this only works for finding total size of table. How to get size of a specific partition from a time-partitioned table, for example I want to find out how much data is stored in mytable$20180701.

I know I can for example copy that partition to a non-partitioned table and use the method above, but I feel this can't be the right method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`dryRun`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.dryRun) for this - or in UI just type `SELECT * FROM mytable$20180701` and see in `Validator` how much bytes will be processed - this is the size of the table

Comment: any way to do it for all partitions?

Comment: Throws `Syntax error: Illegal input character "$" `

Answer (score 0):

In order to access pseduo columns like **PARTITIONS_SUMMARY**, _PARTITIONTIME you can follow the below steps.

1. In the Google Cloud console, open BigQuery page.
2. Click the **More** > **Query settings** button.
3. Scroll down and expand **Advanced options** section, for SQL dialect, select **Legacy**, then click Save.

This will work for fetching pseduo columns. uncheck the **Legacy** option when not required.